# "Could not load file or assembly..." DotNetOpenAuth + MVC3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetopenauth, .net-assembly

I'm getting the following error

```
    Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\<project path>\bin\DotNetOpenAuth.dll'
    or one of it's dependencies. Operation is not supported. 
    (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
```

I get this when I try to add a Controller to my Controllers folder within the MVC3 framework.

I've only recently started using MVC3 and DotNetOpenAuth, I've been using a tutorial to try to learn it, the part I am replicating is this: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-a-model

I can still run the project and everything works fine, I simply cannot add Controllers.

I'm using VS .NET 2010 (64 bit) on Windows 7.

Let me know if there's any additional information that is needed, thank you in advance!

Comment: What version of EF are you using? Check the values of the string connection. Sometimes the `dbContext`can't find the route of the model when creating a Controller. If you are in a hurry, delete that reference, create the Controller and then add the "problematic" reference again, that worked for me once...

Comment: Actually that's how I've been getting by, I delete the reference, produce the controller and then re-add the reference.

Comment: *chuckle*.  There's no such thing as 64-bit VS, btw.  64-bit Windows 7 certainly exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may be related to this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/12/11/visual-studio-project-sample-loading-error-assembly-could-not-be-loaded-and-will-be-ignored-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-operation-is-not-supported-exception-from-hresult-0x80131515.aspx

Which says you need to unblock the assembly within windows explorer.

Comment: This seems like a likely fix, as mentioned before I can bypass the issue by removing the reference while creating the controller, then re-add it afterwards and compile. I have confirmed that my ZIP file has an "Unblock" button. I'd rather not extract it since I've made many changes so far.

Comment: I finally tried this out. Just open the properties of the ZIP file, hit Unblock in Security, extract the file, then re-import it. I only had to re-import the DLL to fix this particular issue.

Comment: One way to avoid this is to extract a zip file using 7z instead of windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [fslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get .NET to log exactly why an assembly could not be loaded.

Comment: That only seems to log assembly load/bind failures that occur at run-time; when I ran this tool and did a build in Visual Studio, Fuslogvw didn't make any log entries.